# How do I troubleshoot this https problem?

Tags: apache, ssl, https

The https of my website does not appear as secure when I use Google Chrome on my desktop, but it does when I use it on my phone.

This is for an Ubuntu server, running WordPress, Let's Encrypt, PHP5 and APache 2. I've tried to install NginX too, but the problem does not get solved. I have no idea what it is going on, plus the fact that this is the first website I am developing by myself.

This is my ufw status:
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Also, everything seems alright when I check the certificates on https://www.ssllabs.com/

My website is [www.floristeriarequena.es](https://floristeriarequena.es)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The https of my website does not appear as secure when I use Google Chrome on my desktop ...

I'm not sure what exactly you mean with this, but your site seem to include resources from `https://68.183.217.125/...`, i.e. you are using the IP address `68.183.217.125` in the URL instead of the hostname  `www.floristeriarequena.es`. Only, the certificate is valid for `www.floristeriarequena.es` and not `68.183.217.125` which results in certificate errors. This results in a failure to load style sheets etc and can be in the developer console seen as:

[image]

Comment: Hi Steffen, I wonder how I should fix the problem. Google Chrome says that my page is not secure yet (in both cases: with the IP Adress and the domain). I'm going to start over and try it again. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @joserequenaidv: since from what I see the embedded links in your site are the problem you need to fix the links. If this is not the problem for you please provide more details than just *"Google Chrome says that my page is not secure"* but the exact and detailed error messages you get.